# Buttons not visible on community record banner or record list component

Tags: lightning, community, customer-community

The buttons are not visible on custom object's Record List component on Community. The layout shows the buttons in place but doesn't show on the community for any user.I am testing using system admin, custom buttons are added on layout and visible on LEX but not on community.
[image]

I can see the the buttons in LEX
[image]

Comment: Typically buttons appear for a user depending on their level of access (for example if you have edit rights on the record - you will see the edit button, if you have delete rights you will see the delete button, and so on). The question here is are you logging into the community with a community user (or yourself)?

Comment: Which buttons are missing exactly?

Comment: @TammerSalem Logging as self, standard and custom buttons all are missing

Comment: Ok - then it's maybe the community components you are using. Have you tried the "Record Banner" component (which should have the buttons as in lightning) and the "Record Detail" (which is the details section)